# cronjob does not stop postgres

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, postgresql

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04
I'm using Postgres that came with apt.

I wrote a simple bash script to stop the database.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

/etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

When running this script in a cronjob owned by root, it does not stop the database.

When I executed the script manually on the command line, it worked as expected. selinux is not enabled.

I then piped STDOUT to a file

```
59 11 * * * /etc/init.d/x.sh >> /var/log/pgsql_tmp.log 2>&1
```

The only output is this.

```
+ /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

Comment: Redirect the STDOUT to file and show us what is the result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed the script to use

```
service postgresql stop
```

and I was able to to get more STDOUT

```
+ /usr/sbin/service postgresql stop
/usr/sbin/service: 169: /usr/sbin/service: systemctl: not found
/usr/sbin/service: 182: /usr/sbin/service: sed: not found
/usr/sbin/service: 187: exec: systemctl: not found
```

For example, to fix,

```
/usr/sbin/service: 169: /usr/sbin/service: systemctl: not found
```

I opened /usr/sbin/service with vim on line 169

```
169    if ! systemctl --quiet is-active multi-user.target
```

and inserted the whole path

```
169    if ! /bin/systemctl --quiet is-active multi-user.target
```

I did it for the others too, now the cron works.

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferred to update the PATH in you crontab file ? Then you should not have to worry about updated overwriting your changes.

Comment: good point @user9517